Why did this native speaker switch tenses in this example?
Here is an excerpt from an essay sample by a native IELTS teacher named Simon:

Looking at the specific second languages spoken, in 2000, 30% of the students were able to speak Spanish, 15% spoke French, and 10% spoke German. By 2010, the proportion of Spanish speakers had risen to 35%, there were 5% fewer French speakers, and the figure for German speakers remained at one in ten.

Why did he switch from the past perfect to the past simple? Can I simply use either tense for all three verbs?

In the example you provided, there are two different time references to consider. The main time reference is given by “by 2010”, requiring a past simple (“there were 5% fewer…”). The past perfect tense, in this case, was used because the rising started in a moment prior to 2010 and reached 35% in 2010. Thus, to indicate an action that started before the main time reference we need a past perfect

Thanks for your answer! What about "there were 5% fewer..."? The decline started at a moment prior to 2010 as well. Shouldn't it be there had been 5% fewer...?

But the sentence doesn't say 'by 2010 the number had declined', just that in 2010 there were fewer than there had been in 2000.

Yes, the decline did start at a moment prior to 2010 but by using the verb “to be” you’re stating the situation in that precise moment (“there were 5% fewer”). With the verb rise you imply a ‘longer’ action, because the number rose from one number (prior to 2010) to another (35%) in 2010.

Oh that makes sense. Thank you both for your help!
